# React DatePicker rompe la estructura de la página al pulsarlo

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Estoy usando el [componente React DatePicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) dentro de un `div` que tiene otros elementos en la misma línea, como se puede ver en la siguiente imagen:

[image]

Cuando hago click en el `input` que muestra el componente DatePicker, el botón de búsqueda queda desplazado a una segunda línea:

[image]

No tengo experiencia con HTML ni CSS por lo que estoy atascado aquí.

Mi código html es bastante simple:

```
 <div className="Search">
    <form>
      <label> Driver ID:
        <input name="driverID" />
      </label>
      <label>  Day:
        <DatePicker/>
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form >
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal para hacer un sitio responsive es usar flex-box . En este caso, tu form tendría que tener la propiedad **display:flex; flex-direction: row;** para indicar que queremos que todo este acomodado en una fila y los labels y el botón, (estos, deberían estar encerrados en un div por cada uno) tendrían que tener la propiedad **flex-direction: column;** asi indicamos que por cada label y el botón tenemos una columna. Luego puedes añadir ** justify-content:center; align-items:center; ** para que este centrado tanto vertical como horizontal.

Comment: @DevGirlC genial, funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias!!